# Can not connect with Bluetooth hc-05

Tags: bluetooth

I connect my Bluetooth hc-05. But the blind led in the Bluetooth module is not stable when I connect with my Android phone. Help help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple really.

Initially the Bluetooth got paired automatically with my Android, but apparently the variable transmission was not complete.

**If this is the case with your module,it will be blinking with high frequency.**

So here is what I did:

1. Hit the RESET button on HC-05 once
2. Go to Android Bluetooth Settings and UNPAIR HC-05
3. Now Pair it again by clicking on it
4. You will be prompted to enter password- '1234'
5. Open your Bluetooth Terminal and you will find your data appearing
   on Android

**P.S.-A 2 Hz blinking frequency on HC-05 should signify proper connection**

Answer (score 0):

Through which android app you are connecting because normally android only pair and will connect to device if you are sharing some data or files or you can connect to android device using any bluetooth app like bluetooth terminal or dual bluetooth chat

Comment: I'm using BT voice